# How to avoid Brython errors on page?

Tags: brython

I started working with **Brython** to create *Python 3 interpreter* on my page. First i created page on **local** and all worked fine, then i pasted same code and resources to my web server and **page started throwing errors** that cannot be fixed, look at page: *(https://sparkztime.com/ides/python/)* and solve this problem, i don't know what I am doing wrong..